# Moment.js Filter out a object whose date property is not after current date

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

I am using moment.js in my predicate function for the filter method on a array of objects who each have an `expiration_date` property.

I would like to filter out the object whose `expiration_date` property is older than today. In my sample array it would be the last one.

```
let dateOfObjects = [
  {
    expirationDate: "9999-12-31",
  },
  {
    expirationDate: "9999-12-31",
  },
  {
    expirationDate: "9999-12-31",
  },
  {
    expirationDate: "9999-12-31",
  },
  {
    expirationDate: "9999-12-31",
  },
  {
    expirationDate: "1999-12-31",
  },
];

    dateOfObjects.filter((el) => {
      return moment.utc(el.expirationDate).isAfter(moment()) === true;
    });
```

I tried to console this before the return

```
console.log('moment.utc(el.expirationDate).isAfter(moment()) ', moment.utc(el.expirationDate).isAfter(moment()) === true);
```

And it is logging true for all the last, but when I console.log `dateOfObjects` I still see it?!

What on earth am I doing wrong?

This example above is in a async function below...

```
async getAllDateStatuses(): Promise<StdDateStatus[]> {
        let dateStatusEntities: StdDateStatusEntity[] = null;
        dateStatusEntities = await this.dbService.getConnection().getRepository(StdDateStatusEntity).find();

        dateStatusEntities.filter((el) => {
            return moment.utc(el.expirationDate).isAfter(moment()) === true;
        });

        return this.populateMultiple(dateStatusEntities);
    }
```

Should that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dateOfObjects.filter()` works just fine for me.

You should know that

> The filter() method does not change the original array.

Source: [Definition and Usage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)

Hence, doing `console.log(dateOfObjects)` will give you the same value even though you did `dateOfObjects.filter()` before it.

So, what you need to do to collect the filtered array is to define `dateOfObjects.filter()` in a variable

Example:

```
const filteredObject = dateOfObjects.filter((el) => {
  return moment.utc(el.expirationDate).isAfter(moment()) === true;
});

console.log(filteredObject);
```

`filteredObject` will be the variable you want.

Comment: Thanks, my brain was fried and I was stressed so I must of forgot that! THANKS!